# In Rust, is there a way to perform a retain() on only part of a container?

Tags: vector, rust, primes

I'm learning Rust for fun, and when writing a function to return the nth prime, I realized my solution felt inelegant and wasteful.

I iterate through my entire list of possible primes, when I only want to iterate through the part of it that hasn't been verified. Is there a way to do this while using the retain() function?

My main issue is that I believe the retain() function is implemented for Vec, and not for a slice. I tried looking into slice documentation for further ideas, but couldn't find any.

Here is the code.

```rust
let mut prime_list: Vec<u32> = (2..n).collect();
let mut i: usize = 0;
while i < prime_list.len() {
    let prime: u32 = prime_list[i];
    prime_list.retain(
       |x| x <= &prime || x % &prime != 0);
    i += 1;
}
```

So the issue is in the function call

```rust
prime_list.retain(
    |x| x <= &prime || x % &prime != 0);
```

I don't need to go over every element in my list each time I pop into this loop since I know that I've verified the elements before 'i'.

But the retain() function needs to go over the entire container, so I add a check into it (x <= &prime || ...) to ignore all the elements before the current one.

What I'd like to do is elegantly start at element at position 'i', and go through the list removing elements.

I know I can do this with a less elegant while or for loop, but I'm hoping there is a Rust-way to do this elegantly.

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: here is a possible solution with splitting and filter() that feels more obfuscated than I think it should be... if there is a better way using the filter() method and iterators I'd really appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

```rust
// inside the while loop
let prime: u32 = prime_list[i];
let (left, right) = prime_list.split_at(i);

prime_list = left.iter()
    .chain(
         right.iter()
         .filter(|x| *x == &prime || *x % &prime != 0))
    .map(|&x| x)
    .collect();

i += 1;
```

Comment: Would something like [`filter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter) on an iterator work? I don't quite understand your prime number algorithm.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response! I'm not sure if a filter() would work, because I want to mutate and return the prime_list outside of the while loop. If I did a filter() wouldn't I have to collect() the result and somehow reassign it to the prime_list variable? I'm not sure if I could re-assign... but I can try that out real quick.

Comment: Alright, I updated it, but I'm not sure this solution is better. I updated the post with the new working version.

Comment: I meant something closer to `prime_list[i..].iter().filter(|| {...}).collect::<Vec<_>>();`

Comment: That works for collecting the part of the vector that I just scanned through, but I'd like to collect the part that doesn't need scanning, along with this filtered part.

So in the edit I think I do something similar to your suggestion here
```rust
right.iter().filter(....)
```
, but since I want both I first split_at() and then chain() them together. For some reason, because it's a slice over references, before I perform the collect() I have to change each element to be values rather than references.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't solve exactly what you wanted, but I thought I'd give a shot at making a more "rust-way" of doing this as someone who has written rust for a little while.

```
let mut primes = Vec::new();

for e in 2..100 {
    if primes.iter().all(|p| e % p != 0) {
        primes.push(e);
    }
}

println!("{:?}", primes);
```

I store the primes in a separate vector because I want to add to it as I go along. This really feels a lot more elegant than trying to use retain to remove certain elements from a vector as you iterate over it.

If you really wanted to get fancy, you could optimize a bit by using `with_capacity` and stopping after you got your nth prime.

```
fn get_nth_prime(n: usize) -> u32 {
    let mut primes = Vec::with_capacity(n);
    let mut e = 2;

    while primes.len() < n {
        if primes.iter().all(|p| e % p != 0) {
            primes.push(e);
        }

        e += 1;
    }

    primes[n - 1]
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks - it might be that my approach to use filter() or retain() to shrink my list of possible primes is what is incorrect. 

I still feel like, there has to be a way in the vein of the EDIT that isn't as obfuscated. But I'll look more into that.

Thanks!