# jump out of Vec::retain()?

Tags: rust, iterator

I want to iterate through a `Vec` doing various things to the objects in it (which would be more complex than `usize`s), and, in the event of an order to stop iterating, retain only the objects which haven't yet been processed.

```
fn main() {
    let _ = iterate();
}

fn iterate(){
    let mut objs_for_processing = Vec::new();
    
    for i in 0..10 {
        objs_for_processing.push(i);
    }
    
    let mut n = 0;
    objs_for_processing.retain(|obj| {
        n += 1;
        if n > 3 {
            println!("STOP iteration!...");
            return true // i.e. retain
        }
        println!("iteration, do some business with obj {}", obj);
        false
    });
    println!("objs_for_processing.len() {} {:#?}", objs_for_processing.len(), objs_for_processing);
}
```

The problem with the above, fairly obviously, is that you have to complete all the iterations, even after you know you want to retain all the other elements...

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56615602/in-rust-is-there-a-way-to-perform-a-retain-on-only-part-of-a-container) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26370894/595305). The latter *seemed* more promising. But then it turns out that you can't change the return type of `retain`'s closure (i.e. to accept a `Result`, so you can then return an `Err` which will stop the iteration), as far as I can tell.

The only solution I've found is to clone the `Vec`, iterate using a normal `for ... in` and then remove items from the clone (called `depleted_vec`) as they are processed, using the rather cumbersome

```
let index = depleted_vec.iter().position(|x| x == obj).unwrap();
depleted_vec.remove(index);
```

... and then to assign `objs_for_processing` to `depleted_vec`. At least this way I can use `break` to stop the iterating.

It seems like a fairly reasonable thing to want to do: isn't there some more elegant way to do this?

NB I also wondered whether there might be an `Iterator`-based solution so I tried with `iter().filter(...).collect()` ... this produces a `Vec` of `&usize`, not `usize`. So it could be used maybe but at cost of additional processing. Not pretty: it just feels like there should be something better.

Comment: Ad "iterator-based solution". You have got references to values inside vectors, because `iter()` will return borrowed iterator. If you want to consume the original vector use `into_iter` instead.

Comment: Also remember that retaining can be expensive operation (because you need to copy a lot of data). Remember that even if you want to "stop" retaining you still need to copy remaining tail of the vector if some elements were removed. Maybe your use case would be better fit with liked list?

Comment: Thanks. `into_iter` works beautifully. First I get a complaint about "cannot infer type"... but this gets solved if you set the original `Vec` to the result of `collect`: `objs_for_processing = objs_for_processing.into_iter().filter(|obj| { ...`. Admittedly, this also involves doing the *whole* iteration again (in `filter`)... but seems like there's probably no way of avoiding that.

Comment: "this also involves doing the whole iteration again" iterators in rust are _lazy_. You can stop iteration early and `drop` iterator, which will free remaining vector elements.

Comment: Ok, I stand corrected. But I don't understand how you'd do that from within the `filter` closure. Or maybe you mean doing it some other way? Perhaps you might like to add an answer with a code snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if I understand this correctly, you need to do two things:

- Iterate over the elements of the vec, doing things with the objects there (modifying them?)
- At some point during iteration, something forces you to stop (e.g. a buffer is full). At this point, you want to remove all the processed items from the vec, so that you can resume work later presumably.

Here's the loop to accomplish this efficiently:

```
let mut n = 0;
for e in &objs_for_processing {
  if must_stop() { break; }
  n += 1;
  process(e);
}
objs_for_processing.drain(0..n);
```

I don't see a point in coming up with anything else, though the experimental `extract_if` API would serve your use case well (would still iterate over everything though).

*However*, if this is really a work queue, you're much better off using a VecDeque in the first place.

```
use std::collections::VecDeque;

fn main() {
    let mut objs_for_processing = (0..10).collect::<VecDeque<_>>();

    let mut n = 0;
    while let Some(obj) = objs_for_processing.pop_front() {
        n += 1;
        if n > 3 {
            println!("STOP iteration!...");
            break;
        }
        println!("iteration, do some business with obj {}", obj);
    }
    println!(
        "objs_for_processing.len() {} {:#?}",
        objs_for_processing.len(),
        objs_for_processing
    );
}
```

Link to playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=78468b26d34a29009b090a969fd9d5f3

Comment: Great. Yes, you've surmised what I want to do precisely. And I had seen and wondered about `Vec::drain`... I've never seen `VecDeque` and probably don't need it: at first glance I can't see that this would be superior to your excellent and simple `for` solution (at least in a single-thread context, which this obviously is).

Comment: @mikerodent `VecDeque` doesn't need to shift elements around as you remove things from the front. That's a big efficiency advantage.

Comment: Right. In my use case this won't matter, but will file this away for future reference. I presume `drain` is a well-optimised way of discarding a slice of a `Vec`.

Comment: In fact, as a matter of policy, it would probably be better to build this `Vec` in reverse order (in my particular case order is irrelevant)... and then start iterating from the END of the `Vec` ... because your remark reminded me of something I had read in The Rust Book about allocating `Vec`s. The point being (as you hint) that it's far easier to free memory at the end of storage than at the beginning. I'm not clear (at my level) whether as Rust practitioners we need to be concerned with this, or whether the Rust compiler/optimiser is so hot it can abstract such concerns away...

Comment: @mikerodent No, that's beyond the optimizer's ability. If you don't continuously produce items and the order doesn't matter, then working from the back is indeed better, and since the code is even more readable, you should *absolutely* do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to clone the `Vec`, you can just iterate using indices and remove the elements:

```rust
let mut i = 0;
let mut n = 0;
while i < objs_for_processing.len() {
    if n > 3 {
        println!("STOP iteration!...");
        break;
    }
    
    if true {
        let obj = &objs_for_processing[i];
        println!("iteration, do some business with obj {}", obj);
        
        objs_for_processing.remove(i);
        // Don't increment `i`!
    } else {
        i += 1;
    }
    
    n += 1;
}
```

This won't be as efficient as `retain()` (as it can do bulk-remove), but it probably doesn't matter for you.

Comment: Thanks. I think I can see what you're doing with this, and it looks there's an efficient solution here ... but as written `i += 1;` is unreachable code.

Comment: @mikerodent Yes. I added it for the case where you don't want to remove _all_ first three  elements, only if a certain condition is true.